Generate math plots and put them properly inside tikz node
I will appreciate if I can get suggestions on how to modify the following code to generate the same plot as the provided figure. I'd like to generate the same SED plot inside the box as well
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Images
\node at (0, 0) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}}; % Replace with actual image
\node at (0, -4) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}}; % Replace with actual image

% Neural network layers (Encoder)
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n1) at (2, 0.25) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n2) at (2, -0.25) {};

\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n3) at (3, 0.5) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n4) at (3, 0) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n5) at (3, -0.5) {};

\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n6) at (4, 0.25) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n7) at (4, -0.25) {};

% Edges between nodes
\foreach \i in {1,2}
    \foreach \j in {3,4,5}
        \draw[-] (n\i) -- (n\j);

\foreach \i in {3,4,5}
    \foreach \j in {6,7}
        \draw[-] (n\i) -- (n\j);

%Decoder Network
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n9) at (2, -3.5) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n10) at (2, -4.00) {};

\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n11) at (3, -3.75) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n12) at (3, -3.25) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n13) at (3, -4.25) {};

\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n14) at (4, -3.5) {};
\node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n15) at (4, -4.00) {};

% Edges between nodes
\foreach \i in {9,10}
    \foreach \j in {11,12,13}
        \draw[-] (n\i) -- (n\j);

\foreach \i in {11,12,13}
    \foreach \j in {14,15}
        \draw[-] (n\i) -- (n\j);
% Latent space box
\draw[rounded corners, fill=purple!10] (7, 0) rectangle (10.5, -4);

% SDE Trajectories
\begin{scope}
\clip (4.5, -2) rectangle (10.5, -1);
\draw[green] plot[domain=4.5:10.5, samples=100, smooth, variable=\x] (\x, {sin(10*\x r)/10+rand/10});
\draw[green] plot[domain=4.5:10.5, samples=100, smooth, variable=\x] (\x, {sin(8*\x r)/15+rand/10});
\draw[green] plot[domain=4.5:10.5, samples=100, smooth, variable=\x] (\x, {cos(9*\x r)/12+rand/10});
\end{scope}

% Path arrows
\draw[->, thick] (7, 0.25) -- (10, 0.25);
\draw[->,thick] (2, 0.75) -- (4., 0.75);
\draw[->,thick] (4, -3.) -- (2., -3.);
\draw[->,thick] (10.5, -4.25) -- (7.5, -4.25);
\draw[->,thick, color=red] (5.75, -2) -- (5.75, -4.5);



% Gaussian distribution (rotated 90 degrees)
\node at (4, -2.75)
{
    \begin{axis}[width=1.5cm, height=1.cm, axis lines=box, samples=100, domain=-3.:3., scale only axis, rotate=270, ticks=none, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
        \addplot[very thick, purple] {exp(-(x+0.5)^2) + 1.15*exp(-((x-1.5)/1.2)^2) + 0.75*exp(-((x+2.5)/0.8)^2)};
    \end{axis}
};
\node at (5.0, -1.0) {$q(\mathbf{z}_0|\mathbf{x})$};
\node at (5.5,-5)
{$\mathbf{D}_{\mathrm{KL}}\big[q(z_0|x)||p(z_0)\big]$};
% Gaussian distribution (rotated 90 degrees)
\node at (5.5, -4.0)
{
    \begin{axis}[width=4cm, height=1.cm, axis lines=box, samples=100, domain=-3.:3., scale only axis, rotate=270, ticks=none, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
        \addplot[very thick, purple] {exp(-((x+0.65)/0.95)^2) + 1.12*exp(-((x-1.25)/1.25)^2) + 0.85*exp(-((x+2.45)/0.95)^2)};
    \end{axis}
};
\node at (6.5, 0.5) {$p(\mathbf{z}_0)$};
\node at (10, -4.0)
{
    \begin{axis}[width=4cm, height=1.cm, axis lines=box, samples=100, domain=-3.:3., scale only axis, rotate=270, ticks=none, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
        \addplot[very thick, purple] {exp(-(x)^2)};
    \end{axis}
};
\node at (11.25, 0.55) {$p(\mathbf{z}_{\text{T}})$};

% Labels
\node at (3, 1) {Encoder};
\node at (3, -2.75) {Decoder};
\node at (9, 0.5) {Latent Space Diffusion};
\node at (9, -4.5) {Latent Space Denoising};


% Adjusted axis for SDE Trajectories
\begin{axis}[
    at={(8, -3)},
    rotate=180,% Positioning the plot inside the latent space diffusion box
    anchor=north west,
    width=6cm, height=4cm,
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=-0.75, ymax=0.75,
    axis lines=none,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty
]
\addplot[blue, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
    {0.2*x + 0.3*sqrt(x)*rand};
\addplot[red, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
    {0.15*x - 0.2*sqrt(x)*rand};
\addplot[black, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
    {0.12*x + 0.4*sqrt(x)*rand};
\addplot[orange, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
    {0.05*x - 0.25*sqrt(x)*rand};
\addplot[purple, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
    {0.2*x + 0.85*sqrt(x)*rand};
\end{axis}

% Probability Flow label
\node at (8.5, -3.8) {Probability Flow};

\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{diffusion with latent variables}
    \label{fig:DLV}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Thanks.

you can help people to help by using example-image as the image (it is generally available for tests) and completing the test file to be a complete document including any needed packages

Draw the NN etc. in separate files, using class standalone. Compile and include like you would with a bitmap-format: includegraphics knows, it looks for a pdf (unless you also provide a jpg etc. with the same name) ... AND it's still a vectorgraphic ...

@DavidCarlisle I add more details so you can run it hopefully.

You shouldn't place Tikz inside Tikz (which pgfplot is based on) % Gaussian distribution (rotated 90 degrees) \node at (4, -2.75) {     \begin{axis} ... . Instead follow the standalone route: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725316/generate-math-plots-and-put-them-properly-inside-tikz-node#comment1805198_725316

Here is a way to do it. Kindly watch my comments in the code, especially in the beginning.
The benefits are: you'll gain much more freedom to operate, and reduce unwanted interactions, e.g. among positions.

main.tex
If you want the figure environment, include this main.pdf (!) e.g. in a document with article class. See e.g. here for an example.
For the remaining arrows and labels you should assign more node names AND relate positions more closely via anchors. This makes positioning more self-consistent. No, you don't need tikzlibrary positioning for this.
The SDE plot in the middle doesn't seem to do anything. I suggest to treat it like nerau.tex, gauss.tex etc., i.e. make it external.
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{tikz}  % already loaded, see above

%\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes.geometric, arrows.meta} % unused ...
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% ~~~ REFACTORING ~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   * (preliminary deleting figure: standalone creates 3 "pages"
%   * refactoring both neural networks (file)
%   ! coordinates are preliminary guesses TO BE IMPROVED
%   * refactored noded gauss (file)
%   * refactored noded gauss2 (file)
%   * refactored noded gauss3 (file)
%   * refactored noded sdetraj (file)
%   * eliminating unused tikz- and pgfplotslibraries

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
%    \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Images // Replace with actual image
\node at (0,  0) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}};
\node at (0, -4) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}}; 

% Neural network layers (Encoder) and Decoder Network
\node[anchor=west] at (1.8,0) {\includegraphics{neural}};
\node[anchor=west] at (1.8,-3.75) {\includegraphics{neural}};


\draw[rounded corners, fill=purple!10] (7, 0) rectangle (10.5, -4);

%% SDE Trajectories // Doesn't seem to be relevant
%\begin{scope}
%\clip (4.5, -2) rectangle (10.5, -1);
%\draw[green] plot[domain=4.5:10.5, samples=100, smooth, variable=\x] (\x, {sin(10*\x r)/10+rand/10});
%\draw[green] plot[domain=4.5:10.5, samples=100, smooth, variable=\x] (\x, {sin(8*\x r)/15+rand/10});
%\draw[green] plot[domain=4.5:10.5, samples=100, smooth, variable=\x] (\x, {cos(9*\x r)/12+rand/10});
%\end{scope}

% Path arrows
\draw[->, thick] (7, 0.25) -- (10, 0.25);
\draw[->,thick] (2, 0.75) -- (4., 0.75);
\draw[->,thick] (4, -3.) -- (2., -3.);
\draw[->,thick] (10.5, -4.25) -- (7.5, -4.25);
\draw[->,thick, color=red] (5.75, -2) -- (5.75, -4.5);


% Gaussian distribution (rotated 90 degrees)
\node[anchor= west] at (4.5, -2) {\includegraphics{gauss}};

\node at (5.0, -1.0) {$q(\mathbf{z}_0|\mathbf{x})$};
\node at (5.5,-5)
{$\mathbf{D}_{\mathrm{KL}}\big[q(z_0|x)||p(z_0)\big]$};

% Gaussian distribution (rotated 90 degrees)
\node [anchor=north east] at (7,0.1) {\includegraphics{gauss2}};
\node at (6.5, 0.5) {$p(\mathbf{z}_0)$};

\node[anchor=north west] at (10.5, .1){\includegraphics{gauss3}};
\node at (11.25, 0.55) {$p(\mathbf{z}_{\text{T}})$};

% Labels
\node at (3, 1) {Encoder};
\node at (3, -2.75) {Decoder};
\node at (9, 0.5) {Latent Space Diffusion};
\node at (9, -4.5) {Latent Space Denoising};


%% Adjusted axis for SDE Trajectories
\node[rotate=180] at(2,-1.7) {\includegraphics{sdetraj}};

% Probability Flow label
\node at (8.5, -3.8) {Probability Flow};

\end{tikzpicture}
%    \caption{diffusion with latent variables}
%    \label{fig:DLV}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}

neural.tex
This clearly is a duplicate, and an opportunity for refactoring by generalization (done in main.tex).
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n1) at (2, 0.25) {};
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n2) at (2, -0.25) {};
    
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n3) at (3, 0.5) {};
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n4) at (3, 0) {};
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n5) at (3, -0.5) {};
    
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n6) at (4, 0.25) {};
    \node[draw, circle, fill=green!30] (n7) at (4, -0.25) {};
    
    % Edges between nodes
    \foreach \i in {1,2}
        \foreach \j in {3,4,5}
            \draw[-] (n\i) -- (n\j);
    
    \foreach \i in {3,4,5}
        \foreach \j in {6,7}
            \draw[-] (n\i) -- (n\j);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

gauss.tex
All gauss-drawings share the same axis options ... which should be refactored out.
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=1.5cm, 
        height=1.cm, 
        axis lines=box, 
        samples=100, 
        domain=-3.:3., 
        scale only axis, 
        rotate=270, 
        ticks=none, 
        xtick=\empty,
         ytick=\empty
    ]    
    \addplot[very thick, purple] {exp(-(x+0.5)^2) + 1.15*exp(-((x-1.5)/1.2)^2) + 0.75*exp(-((x+2.5)/0.8)^2)};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

gauss2.tex
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=4cm, 
        height=1.cm, 
        axis lines=box, 
        samples=100, 
        domain=-3.:3., 
        scale only axis,
         rotate=270, 
         ticks=none, 
         xtick=\empty, 
         ytick=\empty
    ]
    \addplot[very thick, purple] {exp(-((x+0.65)/0.95)^2) + 1.12*exp(-((x-1.25)/1.25)^2) + 0.85*exp(-((x+2.45)/0.95)^2)};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

gauss3.tex
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=4cm, 
        height=1.cm, 
        axis lines=box, 
        samples=100, 
        domain=-3.:3., 
        scale only axis, 
        rotate=270, 
        ticks=none, 
        xtick=\empty, 
        ytick=\empty
    ]
    \addplot[very thick, purple] {exp(-(x)^2)};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

sdetraj.tex
\documentclass[10pt,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%       at={(8, -3)},
%       rotate=180,% Positioning the plot inside the latent space diffusion box
%       anchor=north west,
        width=6cm, height=4cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=1,
        ymin=-0.75, ymax=0.75,
        axis lines=none,
%       xtick=\empty,
%       ytick=\empty
    ]
    \addplot[blue, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
        {0.2*x + 0.3*sqrt(x)*rand};
    \addplot[red, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
        {0.15*x - 0.2*sqrt(x)*rand};
    \addplot[black, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
        {0.12*x + 0.4*sqrt(x)*rand};
    \addplot[orange, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
        {0.05*x - 0.25*sqrt(x)*rand};
    \addplot[purple, thick, domain=0:1, samples=100] 
        {0.2*x + 0.85*sqrt(x)*rand};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

